# What's the meaning of 29/6?

Tags: meaning

I'm reading an Arnold Bennet's book and in a passage of the text appears the following sentence:

> "I want one of those hunters you have in the window at 29/6," said Richard.

Richard looks at a watch (hunters) in a shop window at 29/6 and he wants to buy it. I think 29/6 refers to the price of that watch, but what does it mean? 29 pounds and 6 pence?

Answer (score 7):

29/6 means "29 shillings and six pence." It's the way the old pre-decimal currency was written in Britain. (See [Old English Money](http://projectbritain.com/moneyold.htm)).

> Amounts less than a pound were also written as:
>   12/6 meaning 12s-6d
>   10/- meaning ten shillings.

(Where *s* stood for shilling and *d* for pence.)

It would hardly have been 29 pounds, since that would have been a considerable sum of money for the period.

Comment: Nice, I did wonder at the sum.

Comment: 29/6 was more often written as 1/9/6 (one pound, nine shillings and sixpence) but for sums under two or three pounds the form with just shillings and pence was also used. Twenty nine pounds and six shillings would have been written as 29/6/-, with the - meaning no pence.

Comment: @ColinFine:  Sums under about 40/- were more commonly written s/d, not l/s/d.  29/6 is the common form.  It was also normal in speech to refer to 29 shillings rather than split it to one pound and nine shillings.

Comment: Any idea what this would make the clock worth nowadays?

Comment: @Bladorthin The book was written in 1898; in terms of abstract purchasing power 29/6 would be about £150 today. But there are all sorts of ways of comparing values across time; that number doesn't take into account changes in things like wage scales and household incomes.

Comment: @StoneyB: According to [one web site](https://www.measuringworth.com/ukcompare/relativevalue.php?use%5B%5D=CPI&use%5B%5D=NOMINALEARN&year_early=1898&pound71=29&shilling71=6&pence71=0&amount=29.3&year_source=1898&year_result=2016), "In 2015, the relative value of £29   6s   0d from 1898 ranges from £2,943.00 to £32,160.00." Still a considerable sum.

Comment: @StoneyB: I meant to enter that. The £29 sum was what the OP thought the 29 might represent. Read the last sentence in my answer, where I said that sum was rather outrageous for the item.

Comment: @Robusto Ah, I misunderstood -- I thought you were correcting my £150.

Comment: @StoneyB: No, the misunderstanding is apparently mine. I thought you two were talking about the £29 figure! ^_^

Comment: @Robusto Come to think of it you may very well be right about Bladorthin--in which case I made two mistakes instead of just one!

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey A hunter is a watch, not a clock. In that era, it would have been a pocket watch, and if for a gentleman, gold, with a gold chain. A gold (14K) pocket watch hunter today would be about $3,000.  A steel hunter today  would be fifty to several hundred dollars.  "A hunter-case pocket watch is a case with a spring-hinged circular metal lid or cover, that closes over the watch-dial and crystal, protecting them from dust, scratches and other damage or debris" [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocket_watch).